# Validation to check whether its a ".txt" file

Tags: java, validation, mime

I have this particular piece of code for restricting the users to upload image files only.

```
  if (!fileName.getContentType().startsWith("image/")) 
  errors.add("", new ActionError("errors.imageFile.contentType"));
```

Similary I want the users to upload only files with extension ".txt" in another scenario. What MIME type should I use or please let me know the code which will be helpful for achieving this task.

Comment: according to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html)  you should use **text/plain**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the mime type for text files is `text/plain`

Answer (score 2):

Text files have the following MIME type:

```
text/plain
```

However, according to [this](http://www.feedforall.com/mime-types.htm) site, it is not the only one. You can use Apache's [FileNameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) [getExtension](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) method to get the extension of the file.

Answer (score 1):

> What MIME type should I use ..?

**Content-Type:** text/plain

Answer (score 1):

> I want the users to upload only files with extension ".txt" in another scenario.

The mime type for plain text files is "text/plain".  Or you can check the name of the uploaded file.

However, these won't *prevent* users uploading non-text files.  All they need to do (on Windows) is to rename a non-text file to have the ".txt" extension ... and then upload it.

If you really want to make sure that users only upload text, you need to test the files after they have been uploaded.